# Red5: Flash stream publish stops immediately

Tags: flash, actionscript, red5, netstream

Years ago I've made a little flash applet that streams webcam video to red5 server. Now I tried to "reproduce" my work, but something may went wrong with the current Red5 or Flash versions.

After publishing the stream it stops in less then a second.

ActionScript code (more detailed: http://pastebin.com/ua70kFHu ):

```
...
myStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, myStreamStatus);
myStream.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, myAsyncErrorHandler);
myStream.attachCamera(myCamera);
myStream.publish('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890', 'live');
...
```

Red5 log shows ( more detailed: http://pastebin.com/eLqmCfqB ):

```
...
2012-06-03 20:30:57,408 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  org.red5.demos.oflaDemo.Application - W3C x-category:stream x-event:publish c-ip:10.0.0.5 x-sname:832c7d0c-ae26-4650-9570-a983c2c751d8 x-name:1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
2012-06-03 20:30:57,410 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  o.r.s.stream.ClientBroadcastStream - Close
2012-06-03 20:30:57,411 [NioProcessor-1] INFO  org.red5.demos.oflaDemo.Application - W3C x-category:stream x-event:unpublish c-ip:10.0.0.5 cs-bytes:3552 sc-bytes:3500 x-sname:832c7d0c-ae26-4650-9570-a983c2c751d8 x-file-length:0 x-name:1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
...
```

Please let me know if You have any clue about the problem (or how to debug it).

Comment: So far i have figured out that Red5 is working fine. With the boundled simplebroadcaster demo i can publish a live stream. I think there is something wrong with Flash CS6...

Comment: Solved... the netstream variable was declared inside a function, it must be defined outside (interesting that this worked before).